# Kibana - socket hang up error

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-plugin

I am running Kibana behind IIS reverse proxy server and getting following error

**Courier Fetch Error: unhandled courier request error: socket hang up
I am on Version: 4.2.2, Build: 9177.** 
I get this error only when I use proxy server which I need to restrict access to Kibana. I am not sure what is causing this or how to fix it.

```
Error: unhandled courier request error: socket hang up
at handleError (http://kibana-server/bundles/kibana.bundle.js:70047:23)
at DocRequest.AbstractReqProvider.AbstractReq.handleFailure (http://kibana-server/bundles/kibana.bundle.js:69967:15)
at http://kibana-server/bundles/kibana.bundle.js:69861:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at http://kibana-server/bundles/kibana.bundle.js:69859:19
at wrappedErrback (http://kibana-server/bundles/commons.bundle.js:39286:79)
at http://kibana-server/bundles/commons.bundle.js:39419:77
at Scope.$eval (http://kibana-server/bundles/commons.bundle.js:40406:29)
at Scope.$digest (http://kibana-server/bundles/commons.bundle.js:40218:32)
at Scope.$apply (http://kibana-server/bundles/commons.bundle.js:40510:25)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled Integrated Windows Authentication in your IIS the Kibana server cannot process the request, because the http-Authorization-Header is too large (group memberships are stored in the PAC field of the kerberos tickets).

We had the same Problem with an Apache reverse proxy server in front of Kibana. The solution is to unset the Authorization-Header after Kerberos/NTLM-Authentication is done and before sending the proxy request to Kibana.

Configuration for Apache:

RequestHeader unset Authorization

Answer (score 0):

Try removing http.cors and http.compression as noted in https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6719